# Distribution of hitting time of arbitrary brownian bridge

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose that $B_t$ is a Brownian bridge from $a$ to $b$ on an interval $[0,T]$ (i.e., a Brownian motion $W_t$ such that $W_0=a$ conditioned to satisfy $W_T=b$).

Let $T_c=\inf\{t\leq T:B_t=c\}\land T$ be the hitting time of some point $c\in\mathbb R$ for the bridge in question. Does there exist exact formulas for the cdf/density of $T_c$, similar to the distribution of hitting times for a standard Brownian motion?

Comment: See this for $a=b=0$: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14184/brownian-bridges-first-passage-time-distribution